# Problem with layout in website

Tags: html, css

I built a website. I used liquid layout for all the div tags. And its working fine. The problem i face is when i reduce the screen resolution to 800*600 from 1024*768 the text size isn't reducing ;the text in one div is overlapping with text in another div. I mentioned the size of text in pixel. Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Does your site need to be viewable at 800x600? We've found that there was less than 100 users over the course of a year-long period with that resolution on a site with many millions of visits.

Answer (score 1):

The text size won't reduce with the scale of it's container.  You can set `overflow: auto;` on this container, and it will scroll the content inside of it (when it doesn't fit) instead of letting it overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is your text NOT shrinking; simply add some JavaScript functionality to reduce the text size as the window shrinks. If you HAVE to do this for your website to work properly then, dude, redesign the website...

Comment: redesign the website means should i use fixed layout

Comment: Not necessarily, but redesign your website so it can handle common resolutions. If the only way to do that is using a fixed layout, then by all means you should.

Comment: What about using [these units](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Javascript's [window.screen usage](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml); you should be able to detect their resolution, and execute a function to set the starting font size.  I'm not a Javascript master, but it'd look something like...

```
document.onload = initTextSize;

function initTextSize() {
    var width = screen.width;
    var height = screen.height;

    if(width<=800 && height<=600) {
         document.getElementByTagName("head").innerHTML('<style type="text/css">body { font-size : 1em; }</style>');
    }
    else if(width<=1024 && height<=768) {
         document.getElementByTagName("head").innerHTML('<style type="text/css">body { font-size : 1.6em; }</style>');
    }

}
```

I know you could do it with a switch/case function too, but this is just my rough estimation of how you'd go about it with Javascript.  I think innerHTML *replaces* the content (at least in some browsers,) while you'd want to *append* the new content to your existing stylesheet.

Plus, you might want to account for screen size changes--or who knows... on document load might not be the best way to call the function, but this should point you in the right direction.